# jQuery - how to hide an element if ANY of the activating elements are opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hide

To further clarify this problem, here's the current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/Laqqw/1/

I need to hide the bottom element, when ANY of the navs are opened. And when all the navs are closed, the bottom element would show up again.

toggle() doesn't work, because it sometimes ends up not showing the bottom element when all the navs are closed. 
I tried using if else with no sensible results. Am I missing something here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("h1, h2").click(function() {
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $("footer").toggle(300);
        $("#nav1, #nav2, #nav3").click(function() {
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            if ($("#nav1, #nav2, #nav3").data("clicked")) {
                $("footer").hide(300);
            } else {
                $("footer").show(300);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("h1, h2").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300, function(){
            if($("p:visible").length == 0)
                $("footer").show(300);
            else
                $("footer").hide(300);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laqqw/3/)

Comment: Smart solution, better than mine

Comment: some note about the check `p:visible`, it should be done in the `done` callback of the `slideToggle`. It's worth being added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("p").hide();
$("h1, h2").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
  $("footer").toggle(300);
    $("#nav1, #nav2, #nav3").click(function() {
        $(this).data("clicked", true);
        if ($("#nav1, #nav2, #nav3").data("clicked")) {
            $("#footer").hide(300);
        } else {
            $("#footer").show(300);
        }
    });
});
```

});